# CSS/HTML <a> tag minumum size and background image

Tags: html, css

I have a link that will consist on of 1 image and nothing else. I also need this image to highlight when user hovers over it. I was thinking: use `<a>` tag and set its height, width and background-image properties in CSS. However, (and I've had a feeling it might do that) the `<a>` tag's size when rendered in browser is 0x0. I can include a couple of   characters between the link tag (and the image shows up ok) but it feels a bit hacky. I was also thinking to use the old trick of 1px transparent image set to the correct size - but this also seems less than correct way of doing it. I also can do the same thing with jQuery (but this seems like trying to kill a fly with a sledge hammer).

Is there an alternative pure CSS/HTML way of achieving this?

Comment: If the image consists of just an image, then the image must convey the purpose of the link. Thus it must be content and not just presentational so it needs to be represented using an `<img>` element and not a `background-image`.

Use a real image, and apply JS to swap it out for the highlight effect (presuming that the highlight isn't something like a border, or a change that can be applied via translucency).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set it to `display:block;`, by default a tags are set to display inline. You can then set width and height.

By changing the background-position on hover, or changing the background-image, you can do the rollover.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. However `display:inline-block;` will work better because the element can have size set but remains inline, so it won't mess with the page layout like `display:block;` will.

Comment: so `a` tags can have the background-image property?

Answer (score 1):

And for the background image, you should use a [sprite map](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).  This means make one large image that consists of each image you want to display and only showing part of it as the background.  This is really good to do because it pre-loads the hovered image so there is no lag for the user.  I also find that it organizes my image directories a bit (instead of having an on/off image for every button I just have one image)

Comment: How does this address the issue with the size of the `a` element? That's the central aspect of the question.

Comment: Rich Bradshaw has the answer to that, there is nothing more to add (sure there are different ways to do it).  But if he just follows that he is going to have that laggy hover (and I don't know about you but I don't like going to a website and getting that)

Comment: So it's a comment expanding on his answer, then, not an answer. (A useful comment, don't get me wrong.)